# Zeroing empty sectors on various Linux filesystems

Tags: file-system

There exist various tools for Windows filesystems (NTFS, FAT) to write zeroes or random numbers to free space on the drive/filesystem.

Do there exist tools like this for Linux filesystems like ext4 and btrfs?

Comment: Probably duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4

Answer (score 2):

There are various tools for the task. It depends on what are think exactly.

If you want to securely delete an already existing file, then the `zerofree` and `sfill` tools are for you (as you can read on @BobBrown's link). If these are not available, or you like more do things combining system functionality instead of downloading toos for everything, then there is another solution:

1. You set a loopback device from the file to erase (`losetup /dev/loop0 /this/file/to/delete`).
2. From this point you can pay with `/dev/loop0` without the fear that it freed the block of `/this/file/to/delete` instead of rewriting. You can safely fill them with zeros (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/loop0`), or with random numbers (using `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/zero`)m even multiple times if you want.
3. If you are ready, deallocate the loopback (`losetup -d /dev/loop0`), and you can safely delete the now rewritten file.

There is another case, if you want to make some *already* *deleted* file unrecoverable. In this case you had to ask "free" and not "empty" sectors. The problem is, that you can't address or manipulate sectors on a filesystem, which doesn't belong to any file. Even this is because it is free.

But there is a workaround. If you create a file enough big to fill *the* *whole* *free* _space *on* *the* *hard* *disk* if you fill it zeroes or random numbers, you will surely overwrite all free sectors in your system. So, there is very simple what you had to do: simply fill you partition with a big, empty file, until it doesn't stop with a "filesystem full" or similar error:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/filler
```

...is even enough. While it works, you can even watch with some `df` commands, how are the things going. After `/filler` filled your disk with random bytes, and then the `dd` command stopped with the error, it is practical to `sync` one (to make sure everything is really overwritten), and then you can remove the `/filler`.

There were enough to protect from everything which a normal human can do to recover your data. If you want yet more, you had to replay that 3 or even more than 10 times. Even the NSA doesn't do more.

Comment: So there's no tool available to fill all _empty_ sectors then?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Probably there is, and here I explained, why isn't it really needed (although you can use a such thing if you want).